# How to secure an AWS Gateway REST API to be accessed by a publicly accessible web page (React)

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cognito, websecurity

I have a REST API exposed in AWS API Gateway serving some backend data and I plan to consume this via a React UI I'm developing (read only) and some admin scripts (not read only).  The data I'm serving is not sensitive at the moment, but I would like to put some basic security up around it so that only I (or the apps I write) can access and manipulate it.  My question is: how do I secure the API so that a publicly accessible UI can interact with it?  My first impulse was to use Cognito User Pools/JWT but the examples I've seen always tie this to some login flow on the client side (which I don't have).

Comment: Can you clarify what do you mean by "security access to API" without any form of authentication, such as cognito?

Comment: I will not require users to login in to the web page to view content.  So I would like the app to authenticate to the API behind the scenes to load data, but not bother the user with any sort of login.  I'm wondering if that is a good use case for Cognito or if there's something else I should be considering.

Comment: There is no other way except to login.

Answer (score 1):

You can set API Key at your API Gateway, and set it to your header when you make HTTP Call from your React frontend. Without the correct API Key presented in your header. It won't able to access. More details here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-api-usage-plans.html